# Error 400 on puppet SERVER

Tags: puppet

On agent node:

```
root@agent2-VirtualBox:/var/lib/puppet# puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Could not find default node or by name with 'agent2-virtualbox.servicemesh.com, agent2-virtualbox.servicemesh, agent2-virtualbox, agent2-VirtualBox.servicemesh.com, agent2-VirtualBox.servicemesh, agent2-VirtualBox' on node agent2-virtualbox.servicemesh.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
root@agent2-VirtualBox:/var/lib/puppet#
```

On the puppet master side:

```
root@puppetmaster:~# puppet cert sign --all
Error: No waiting certificate requests to sign
root@puppetmaster:~#
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide more info, rather then just posting the error. `Introduce the problem before you post any code

In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible.` from [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check you site.pp and make sure you either have a default node definition defined or a node definition for the FQDN of your agent.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_node_definitions.html

for example:

```
node 'agent2-virtualbox.servicemesh.com' {
  import ntp
}
```